# new item count based alerts for review items

Tags: feature-request, review

Can we have the feature for new item alerts (new item count icon) specific to review items. that would help the reviewers to spend time only when needed.

Comment: Can you please clarify your request, I'm not really able to understand your need :)

Comment: i was hoping to have an item count display over the review tab similar to facebook messages/updates icon with count.

Comment: Please see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar (the functionality already exists for users with more than 10k rep and for moderators)

Comment: it's a way long for me.. any how thanks for answering :)